# How to do a "git fetch --all --tags" in Magit?

Tags: magit, git, version-control, tags

I would like to pull changes from an upstream repository. More specifically, I would like to pull **all the tags** that were introduced. On the terminal, I can do:

```bash
$ git fetch --all --tags
```

On Magit, after pressing `F` which is bounded to *Pull*, I have the following options:

[image]

As you see, there is not an option to pull tags.

Is there a way to fetch all tags from upstream/master in Magit?
Am I missing something?

Comment: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/4087

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`magit-fetch` command, usually bound to <kbd>f</kbd>.

[image]